# ImportXML function on Google sheet to pick up date of last commit on GitHub

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to access the last commit date of a repository on Github but I'm getting the message Imported Content is Empty and I'm not sure why.

The code I am using is below

=importxml("https://github.com/rmasey/Example", "/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]/relative-time")

I'm hoping to be able to make a sheet where I list the repo URLs and then show the last commit date of each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a shorter xpath expression, like this one:

```
=importxml("https://github.com/rmasey/Example", "//relative-time/text()")
```

Output:

```
Oct 16, 2020
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: @Tortoise It certainly works; tried on a 2nd computer. It may be something with your setup - is it possible that your IP address was banned? Other than that, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: OK, I'll do some investigating.  Thank you

Comment: Hello @Tortoise have you come to any conclusion? For me this answer is indeed working. You can change the last bit of `text()` by a single dot (`.`) to see if that change it up.

Comment: @Raserhin It's really frustrating - sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I just don't know why.  I'm just looking at using  URLFetchApp eg var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://github.com/rmasey/Example').getContentText() and then XmlService.parse(html) but I get an error there too - Exception: Error on line 67: Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element type "meta" must be followed